# Why is my if statement not evaluating the correct answer in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

This is my code, creating named column vectors which hold only the nonzero values from the table ALLDATA, the if statement is always evaluating as true:

```
ALLDATA = table2array(readtable(filepath));

% Initialize column vectors
numCols = size(ALLDATA, 2);
colNames = ALLDATA(1,:);

% Iterate over each column
for j = 2:numCols
    % Get column name and initialize column vector, with room only for nonzero, non-title values
    colName = num2str(ALLDATA(1,j));
    colVec = zeros(nnz(ALLDATA(:,j))-1,1);
    
    % Iterate over each value in column
    for i = 2:size(colVec)
        % If value is positive
        if ALLDATA(i,j)~=0
            colVec(i)=ALLDATA(i,j);
        else 
            continue;
            disp("no");
        end
    end

    varName = ['duration_', strrep(colName, ' ', '_')];
    eval([varName ' = colVec;']);
end
```

Please help.

filepath finds a csv of which I've removed the address.

No matter what I do, I cannot get the if statement to evaluate properly. It always evaluates as true regardless of what operator I use.

I've tried:

```
if nnz(ALLDATA(i,j))
if ALLDATA(i,j)>0
```

Also flipped the logic and tried `if ALLDATA(i,j)==0 else continue;`

Comment: Can you give an example data (in text)? I hope you are not replying on that disp(no), because the continue skips it.

Comment: `continue` immediately skips to the top of the inner loop. Its only effect is to skip the `disp` statement, if you leave it out the code will do the same thing except it also displays “no” if the condition is false. That `continue` statement shouldn’t be there.